# Routing can't find $id from mysql table

Tags: mysql, symfony, routes, twig

Im trying to delete a record in my table from a routing. But it doesnt seem to find the given $id. I have a for loop in my application which loops out records from the table, they all have their own unique id.

[My table](https://gyazo.com/bef4c95a06e2b5c8a23f1ccaf9083ce8)

```
     /**
     * @Route ("/scholen/delete/{id}", name="delete_school")
     * Method ({"GET", "POST"})
     */
```

My loop

```
            {% for scholen in scholen %}
                <li>{{ scholen.naam|e }} - <a href="{{ path('delete_school') }}">Delete</a></li>
            {% else %}
                <li>no scholen found</li>
            {% endfor %}
```

EDIT: found a mistake which lead to another. -> I now get this instead

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "delete_aanmelding".").

Comment: `path('delete_school', {id: scholen.id})`

Comment: @Jakumi wow! this worked! Thank you so much. Really couldnt find anything about this.

Comment: well ... "path" is awkwardly named, but it generates a URL for a route (the given one) and thus requires parameters. docs for `path` do exist in the twig bridge, I believe and in the routing section of symfony docs.

Comment: Are you sure you've provided the proper code? According to the error message, a URL for the route `delete_aanmelding` should be generated, but that is not part of your code.